# Should there be a Stack Overflow section where you can ask beginning level programming questions?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, new-users

I would like a section devoted entirely to beginners. I don't understand why the users in Java, Python and C++ are so hostile to beginners, when you don't see the same attitude on Math.Stackexchange.

Comment: I see no need for it.  As long as the question isn't a duplicate and shows research, it should be well-received.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a tutorial website but a Q&A website where you can ask programming problems you are facing. So answer is `NO`.

Comment: If there was a site entirely for beginners, or more particularly beginners who feel their contributions shouldn't be subject to any quality standards, do you really think any experienced users would go there to help them?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no need for a separate section or a separate site. All we ask from you is to ask a good question. Beginner level questions are welcome if they are on actual practical problems you face, when you've done your research and tried something, and the question is not a duplicate.

Stack Overflow however is not there to teach you how to program. It is no substitute for teaching yourself or doing your own research. That you will really have to do by yourself. By picking up a good book for example and working through all its exercises. Or by reading all the material and documentation you can lay your hands on.

If you do all that, and you ask a clear question that follows those guidelines, it will generally be welcomed. If you don't, it might not be. That is not hostility though. That is a minimal level of quality control.

Should users ever be rude to you however, then that is absolutely not tolerated. Feel free to flag any such comments.

Comment: If a resource center could be realised, it would be great, but such question would be closed as a shopping list question. Is the tag wiki where such stuff belongs?

Comment: Possibly @JanDvorak